# Generate flat tree using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

By flat tree I mean a table where each child has a link to its parent. Also tree have to be limited by depth and size (max number of nodes). When object and parent ids are equal it's one of the root nodes. So want to generate data structure like this:

```
id | parent id
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 2
4  | 1
```

I've solved this task, but resulting code somewhat cumbersome:

```java
private static final ThreadLocalRandom RANDOM = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

public static <I, T extends Node<I>> List<T> generateTree(int count,
                                                          int maxDepth,
                                                          Supplier<T> supplier) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(count);
    int remainingDepth = maxDepth;
    while (remainingDepth > 0 && result.size() < count) {
        final boolean firstStep = result.isEmpty();
        final boolean lastStep = remainingDepth == 1;
        final int remainingCount = count - result.size();
        final int generatedCount = !lastStep ?
                RANDOM.nextInt(1, remainingCount + 1) :
                remainingCount;

        List<T> generatedNodes = IntStream.range(0, generatedCount).boxed()
                .map(i -> {
                    T value = supplier.get();
                    value.parentId = firstStep ?
                            value.id : // root node, id = parent id
                            result.get(RANDOM.nextInt(0, result.size())).id; // child node, find random parent
                    return value;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.addAll(generatedNodes);
        remainingDepth--;
    }

    return result;
}

static class Node<I> {
    public I id;
    public I parentId;

    public Node(I id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " | " + parentId;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    List<Node<Integer>> result = generateTree(100, 4, () -> new Node<>(RANDOM.nextInt(100, 1000)));
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Yeah, it can be simplified by remove a couple of unnecessary variables, those just improve readability, but in general I don't see ways to improve the most complex part - obtaining random parent id.

So I wonder is it possible to rewrite this implementation to Stream API (I mean reducers, of course). Will it be simpler? I've tried to do so but functional paradigm just blows my brain. Could someone please help me?

Comment: side note: you could use [`IntStream.mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) instead of `.boxed().map(...)`.

Comment: I’m confused about the way you use random numbers. First, your supplier seems to create nodes with a random ID, without checking for duplicates. Then, it seems you pick a parent from all previously generated nodes, not just from the previous iterations, so how does it relate to the intended depth? The larger the specified maxDepth, the less likely is having nodes in the last level. In principle, you could even end up with all nodes being a direct child of the root…

Comment: @Holger There's nothing wrong. 1) Yes, supplier don't check for duplicate ids. That's why `Node` is parameterized and I use `Supplier`. In real world where will be `UUID`. Integers just for test, because it's easier to read output 2) Yes, because if you pick node from current iteration you can't guarantee max depth. 3) Yes, that's why it called max depth and not guaranteed depth :) It's just a threshold.

Comment: So you always generate `count` objects? And the entire logic is about assigning each node a parent id from the previous level? That surely can be done simpler, by separating those two concerns.

Comment: @Holger Yes, the thing is to generate `count` objects and assign them parent id so that resulting tree depth doesn't exceed max depth. It can be less or even zero (which means it's a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out better solution. It's a custom `Collector`. Also, it's easier to track `depth` when it's just one of node properties, which can easily done via wrapper. Here's an example:

```java
static class Node<I> {
    public I id;
    public I parentId;
    public int depth;

    public Node(I id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " | " + parentId + " | depth: " + depth;
    }
}

public static <I, T extends Node<I>> List<T> generateTreeStream(int count,
                                                                int maxDepth,
                                                                Supplier<T> supplier) {
    Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> collector = Collector.of(
            ArrayList::new,
            (list, node) -> {
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, list.size());
                    T parent = list.get(random);
                    if (parent.depth < maxDepth) {
                        node.parentId = parent.id;
                        node.depth = parent.depth + 1;
                    }
                }
                list.add(node);
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            }
    );

    return IntStream.range(0, count)
            .mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())
            .collect(collector);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don’t see a way to rewrite the assignment of parent IDs using the Stream API to *simpler* code.

Instead, separate the two different concerns of the code 1) generate `count` `Node` objects and 2) assign them parent IDs.

```java
public static <I, T extends Node<I>>
    List<T> generateTree(int count, int maxDepth, Supplier<T> supplier) {

    ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
  
    List<T> result = IntStream.range(0, count)
        .mapToObj(i -> supplier.get())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  
    for(int index = 0, level = 0, numItemsInThisLevel;
        level < maxDepth && index < count; level++, index += numItemsInThisLevel) {
  
        int remaining = count - index;
        numItemsInThisLevel = level < maxDepth - 1? r.nextInt(remaining) + 1: remaining;
  
        for(T value: result.subList(index, index + numItemsInThisLevel))
            value.parentId = index == 0? value.id: result.get(r.nextInt(0, index)).id;
    }
  
    return result;
}
```

Generating `count` objects is straight-forward and should not need further explanation. Your algorithm, as far as I understood, iterates over up to `maxDepth` ranges of the objects and assigns them parent IDs taken from the IDs of random objects before that range. I wrote this as a loop over ranges reflecting exactly that. Note that it would be easy to adapt this to use only IDs from the previous level, to get the specified depth exactly.

One important note: `ThreadLocalRandom` is, as the name suggests, local to the thread and should always get acquired via `current()` by the using thread. So storing it in a `static final` variable means, only the thread that executed the class initializer would be allowed to use that instance. On the other hand, `current()` is cheap, there would be no advantage in caching the result anyway.

Comment: Thx, for the example, but it's still hardly readable without comments :) Just like mine initial one. Anyway I've found out that custom collector is more suitable.